# Submit Hive query in "background"

Tags: hadoop, hive

I can submit a query to Hive like so:

`hive -e "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/my_result_dir' SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 5;"`

When this happens, I get all my progress etc etc spewed out to the console.

For the purposes of what I'm doing, I just want to issue the query, and get back the job ID. I'll separately monitor for completion of the job elsewhere.

Is there a good, non-hacky way to do this? I see [executing HIVE query in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460856/executing-hive-query-in-background) but given the choice, I'd prefer to avoid having to use a temporary file to write this output to and then waiting for that file to contain the information I need. But there doesn't seem to be a flag to tell hive "Yo, just give me back the metadata for this job".